# The 'og:image' property content is not shown in Facebook while sharing the website URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I used the `og:image` meta property content with an image. While sharing my site in Facebook, the image disappeared.

#### HTML

```
<meta property="og:image" 
      content="http://d3piu9okvoz5ps.cloudfront.net/awp-content_1/10930wp10159/uploads/2011/08/GNR_Logo.gif" />
```

Comment: Have you linted your page (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)? Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: the facebook debug tool gives me this issue could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond. i am getting images from cloud front and images are less than 30 kb and also they are valid image urls to if i give the url in browser then the images are being shows but facebook debug tool gives me this error. Kindly help me on this issue please.

Answer (score 5):

The image is too wide, the width/height and heigh/width need to both be <3 (from the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

> og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images with your page.

(your image is 320/99 = 3.23)

Comment: the facebook debug tool gives me this issue could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond. i am getting images from cloud front and images are less than 30 kb and also they are valid image urls to if i give the url in browser then the images are being shows but facebook debug tool gives me this error. Kindly help me on this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

Run your URL through the Debug tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - correct any errors shown.

Can't do this myself as you've not provided your OG object URL.

Comment: the facebook debug tool gives me this issue could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond. i am getting images from cloud front and images are less than 30 kb and also they are valid image urls to if i give the url in browser then the images are being shows but facebook debug tool gives me this error. Kindly help me on this issue please.